# Laravel mix compilation very slow in Docker container

Tags: laravel, docker, npm, docker-compose, laravel-mix

Whenever I run,

```
docker-compose run --rm npm run production
```

Laravel mix takes around 15 minutes to complete the build. I suspect this is due to inherent slowness of Docker Desktop for Windows - I say this because even my Laravel site is loading slowly in my browser when accessed over localhost.

In order to attempt to speed up my Docker Desktop, I have created the following `.wslconfig` file in C:\Users<my_username>,

```
[wsl2] 
memory=8GB
processors=2
```

I am definitely using WSL version 2. Please refer:
[image]

The following https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1936#issuecomment-380257581 was promising: I excluded my project files from my Norton Antivirus' "scannable" files, temporarily disabled my Antivirus.
After doing all of the above, I shutdown my WSL on my Windows by using `wsl --shutdown` which automatically shutdown Docker Desktop. I then restarted Docker Desktop. But after all this,  `npm run production` is still frustratingly slow in my Docker Container.

I would be grateful to understand if I am missing something.

Here is my PC config:

[image]

I am using Windows 10 Home.

Here is the npm snippet from my docker-compose.yml file:

```
npm:
    build:
      context: ./dockerfiles
      dockerfile: node.dockerfile
    container_name: npm
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - 3008:3000
      - 3009:3001
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    entrypoint: ['npm']
    networks:
      - laravel
```

And the contents of *node.dockerfile*:

```
FROM node:14.5.0-alpine
```

The site ( configured using a separate NGINX DOCKER container ) itself is slow to load, this is why I suspect that this is related to Memory size issue of Docker Desktop. But I am happy to accept counter arguments to my theory, probably this might be the result of a misconfigured npm Docker container on my local. But whatever it is, npm is taking hell lot of time to build my project (no matter what I do)!

Comment: If your Dockerfile just contains the `FROM` line and you're bind-mounting everything that would run inside the container, would it be easier to just run Node directly on your host?  Are you hitting the problems described in [docker on wsl2 very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62154016/docker-on-wsl2-very-slow)?

Comment: This may be a personal bias, but I think the reason for the slowness is ultimately Hyper-V.

Comment: In the past, when I completely disabled Hyper-V and created a virtual machine through Virtualbox to run Docker, the same specifications were several times faster than the underlying Hyper-V.

Comment: But I've moved to MAC for development now so not sure if this is still the case.