# How to optimize - PHP 7.3.14 + Laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6, php-7.1

I need to replicate a legacy structure for comparison purposes and to motivate system migration.
I will write a report pointing out the pros and cons of this migration.

But I immediately had a problem, the server is **extremely slow**, I can't compare it with the **web server** in **node/go/rust** which returns less than 3ms in development mode.

The initial framework with **PHP 7.13.4 + Laravel 6** is taking an average of **3 seconds** to return static data.

The repository is below:

[Git - Repository php7.13.4_laravel6](https://github.com/ricardosc12/php7.13.4_laravel6)

To verify:

```
docker compose up -d
```

and

```
GET: http://localhost:8080/api/user
```

The question is that I have just started this structure, do I need to carry out a series of optimizations for this to be minimally acceptable?

Commands executed:

```
composer dump-autoload --optimize
php artisan optimize
php artisan config:cache
php artisan route:cache
```

PC info:

```
Operating System Name: Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
Operating System Version: 10.0.19045 N/A Build 19045
Total Physical Memory: 16,308 MB
Processor: AMD Ryzen 5 3600 6-Core Processor 12 Threads
```

Running in WSL Ubuntu-18.04 - Docker

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably, you are storing your files on Windows. Differences between file systems force to do some kind of conversion, that's where the problem is.

The solution is simple: move your files into WSL (e.g. home directory) and run Docker from it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/filesystems#file-storage-and-performance-across-file-systems

[Docker on WSL2 very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62154016/docker-on-wsl2-very-slow)

Comment: I've been trying for a few hours to run this within the WSL. I made some configurations, but without success. Works on Windows, but with files inside WSL it returns an internal server error

Comment: After some time, and making corrections to the vendor, I discovered that all I had to do was run: 
chmod -R 777 php7.13.4_laravel6/