Excel generation with PHP in docker container is much slower compare to same application on my host machine
I have an app that laravel app that can generate excel file. The performance of excel generation was much slower in docker container. I am using laravel excel for generating the excel file.
# For more information: https://laravel.com/docs/sail
services:
  mysql:
    image: 'mysql:8.0'
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    environment:
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'
    volumes:
      - 'mysql:/var/lib/mysql'
    networks:
      - otonometer

  zipkin:
    image: openzipkin/zipkin:latest
    ports:
      - '9411:9411'
    networks:
      - otonometer

  otonometer:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    develop:
      watch:
        - action: sync+restart
          path: ./nginx/otonometer.com.conf
          target: /etc/nginx/sites-available/otonometer.com.conf
        - action: sync+restart
          path: ./nginx/nginx.conf
          target: /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
        - action: sync
          path: ./
          target: ./var/www/webcore_app
          ignore: [./nginx, ./php, ./mysql]
    ports:
      - "${APP_PORT:-80}:80"
    environment:
      - OTP_URL=zipkin
      - OTP_PORT=9411
    depends_on:
      - mysql
      - zipkin
    networks:
      - otonometer
networks:
  otonometer:
    driver: bridge
volumes:
  mysql:

This is my docker-compose.yml file. And this is my Dockerfile
# Use the official PHP image as the base image
FROM php:8.1.0-fpm
# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /var/www/webcore_app

RUN mv "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini-production" "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini"

## View files
RUN ls -la

## Install dependencies
RUN apt-get clean
RUN apt-get update -yqq &&\
    apt-get install -y nginx && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Update package manager and install dependencies for PHP extensions
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libicu-dev \
    libbz2-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    zip \
    unzip \
    mariadb-client \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) pdo_mysql zip bcmath pcntl exif gd intl opcache xml bz2 
    

# Clean up to reduce the image size
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Copy the Laravel project files into the container
COPY composer.json composer.lock ./

# Install Laravel dependencies using Composer
RUN composer install --no-scripts --no-autoloader

# Copy the rest of the Laravel project files into the container
COPY . .

# Set the correct permissions for the storage and cache directories
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/webcore_app/storage /var/www/webcore_app/bootstrap/cache
RUN chmod -R 775 /var/www/webcore_app/storage /var/www/webcore_app/bootstrap/cache


# Now run autoloader optimization
RUN composer dump-autoload --optimize

# Copy and configure Nginx
COPY ./nginx/otonometer.com.conf /etc/nginx/sites-available/otonometer.com.conf
COPY ./nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

ADD ./php/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d

RUN ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/otonometer.com.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled

RUN nginx -t

EXPOSE 80

# Start Nginx and PHP-FPM
CMD ["sh", "-c", "service nginx start && php-fpm"]

I have suspissions on whether there are some volume attached/mounted to my local host, because i just known that if my app is mounted to host machine it will make performance much slower. But when i look at mount and volumne page on docker console, there were no volume and mount attached. Maybe some one can help me, i am new at docker.

What is your host operating system? Maybe it's unrelated, but I would check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62154016/docker-on-wsl2-very-slow if you are on Windows using WSL

Btw i use windows 11. I am still new in docker, but i already did some optimization, by not mounting my container folder to my windows and everything except generating excel is close to the performance of the app that running in my windows machine.
